# How to use synthetic division when the denominator is $x^2 + 1$?

Tags: polynomials

If the problem is to write the following with simplified polynomials

$$\frac{x^2 + 5x + 6}{x^2+1}$$

Is it possible to do this problem with synthetic division? If so, how?

I've tried googling, finding on youtube, even plug this in Wolfram Alpha, no helpful results :/

Comment: A rational function written in lowest terms is 0 if and only if its numerator is 0. So you can just find zeroes of the numerator.

Comment: @André3000 APOLOGIES!!!! i got the problem wrong. not looking for zeros... just looking for divided version. im so terribly sorry! edited my question too :/

Comment: with a divisor that is not linear, you can use polynomial long division.  I can't imagine doing it in MathJax, but it works pretty much exactly like long division of whole numbers.  It takes a little more space than synthetic division, but it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synthetic division is only used when you have a polynomial divided by a linear divisor.  However, we can *creatively* decompose the numerator into something that we want.

\begin{align}
\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x^2+1}&=\frac{\color{blue}{x^2}+5x+\color{blue}{1}+5}{x^2+1}\\
&=\frac{\color{blue}{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}+\frac{5x+5}{x^2+1}\\
&=1+\frac{5x+5}{x^2+1}\\
\end{align}

Comment: thank you so much! your first sentence answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

To find all zeros of $$\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x^2+1}$$ you have to solve the equation $$x^2+5x+6=0$$
Or this here
$$\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x^2+1}=1+{\frac {5\,x+5}{{x}^{2}+1}}$$
It is $$\frac{x^2+5x+6}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^2+1+5x+5}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: APOLOGIES!!!! i got the problem wrong. not looking for zeros... just looking for divided version. im so terribly sorry! edited my question too :/

Comment: how did you get the 1+()? can you show the work?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions $$x^2+5x+6=(x^2+1)+5x+5$$

Comment: thank you both! i understand it now :)